# How to layout a stack of controls evenly?

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-phone-8.1, stackpanel

I've added a `textbox`, `listpicker flyout`, `timepicker` and `button` controls which are layed out in descending order.

Each of the controls have a **header which is too small** set to detail the purpose of the control.

What I've tried is laying out the controls using the grid row and column positioning, but the controls **aren't evenly spaced** in the layout. Also I can't specify a font size for the header text sizes.

**Question:**

Can anyone suggest a more user friendly layout for the given controls? i.e, bigger header font size and even spacing.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF236A93">

    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Text="Parking Tag Picker" />
        <TextBlock Margin="9,-7,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding CouncilHeaderDisplayName}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--  ContentPanel contains details text. Place additional content here  -->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Height="600"
          Margin="5,0,5,0"
          Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1.6*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1.6*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1.6*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1.3*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="270"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>



        <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.RowSpan="1"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                 Width="270"
                 Height="72"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Background="Azure"
                 x:Name="regNumberTextBox"
                 Header="Registration Number:"
                 Text="{Binding SelectedRegNumber,
                                Mode=TwoWay}"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Width="270"
                   Height="72"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Foreground="LightBlue"
                   Text="Parking Zone:" />

        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="270"
                Height="72"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding SelectedZone, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <Run Text="{Binding ZoneName}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <Button.Flyout>
                <ListPickerFlyout x:Name="ZonePicker"
                                  Title="Parking Zone"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ZoneInfoCollection}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedZone,
                                                         Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListPickerFlyout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" Text="{Binding ZoneName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListPickerFlyout.ItemTemplate>
                </ListPickerFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>


        <TimePicker Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Width="270"
                    Height="100"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Header="Parking Duration:"
                    Time="{Binding SelectedParkDuration,
                                   Mode=TwoWay}" />


        <Button Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="200"
                Height="100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Command="{Binding TagRequestCommand}"
                Content="Send"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsValidTagRequest,
                                    Mode=TwoWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" />

    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a stack panel with orientation set as vertical and set consistent margin's for all the elements inside it to get evenly spaced elements. And as for the header font size you can create a custom HeaderTemplate with desired font size for TextBox and TimePicker.

Comment: Do you have an example of that type of layout?